# How to remove columns based on colSum

Tags: r

I would like to remove columns that have less than 150 from the column sum from my dataframe df1

My dataframe is

```
chr      leftPos    FLD0195  FLD0197 FLD0201 FLD0203 FLD0211    FLD0243
chr1    100260254       34    52       29        18    13       30
chr1    100735342       44   111       88        65    40       66
chr1    100805662        0    0         1         1    0         0
chr1    100839460        1    0         5         0    0         0
```

The formula I'm using is as below. It runs without error but df2 is exactly the same as df1

```
    df2 <- df1[,(colSums(df1[,3:ncol(df1)]) > 100000),]
```

Comment: Do you mean remove rows that have less than 150 from the column sum?

Comment: Your problem is that you are checking sums only for `df1[,3:ncol(df1)]` while sub-setting from the whole data set. You should do something like `cbind(df[1:2], df1[3:ncol(df1)][, colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)]) > 150, drop = FALSE])`

Comment: OK so how to subset based on colSums >10000

Comment: Change 150 to 10000 in @DavidArenburg's code.

Comment: A better option would be just `df1[c(TRUE, TRUE, colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)]) > 150)]` (adjust 150 to 1e5 in your original data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a Boolean expression on a `k` columns subset you are receiving a `k` size logical vector. When entered inside a `n` size column data set, `n-k` values from the beginning of the vector are being recycled (until it reaches the size of `n`), thus wrong columns are being selected. In your case, the fix is simple, just add `n-k` `TRUE` values at the beginning of the logical vector (because you want to keep all the `n-k` columns at the beginning)

```
df1[c(rep(TRUE, 2L), colSums(df1[3L:ncol(df1)]) > 150L)]
#    chr   leftPos FLD0197
# 1 chr1 100260254      52
# 2 chr1 100735342     111
# 3 chr1 100805662       0
# 4 chr1 100839460       0
```